# Inject/override object properties in GTK application

Tags: properties, gtk, overriding, window-decoration

I'd like to inject/override a Gtk Window property at startup, ideally from a GTK config file or from CSS, so that GTK ignores the application startup defaults.

This is the property I'd like to override:
`decorated` https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/property.Window.decorated.html

I'd like to have it set to `false` for every application.
That's a property of `Gtk.Window`, inherited by all windows. As far as I understand it, there's no way to set it via CSS (but I may be wrong).

Is there a way to do that?

If it's not possible, is it possible to at least disable window decoration (like the property would) globally, in GTK?